# How the check if a value is NULL or unassigned in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Suppose in this example, `firstName` is not set and  `lastName` is assigned a value. How to check if the value is assigned or not.

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable();
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');
}
```

Which one is the best approach? Will these work?

```
   if(lastName  == '')
       //do something
```

or

```
   if(lastName)
       //do something
```

or

```
   if(lastName  == null)
       //do something
```

Please help.

Comment: I've often wished for a comfortable solution to this issue. For now it seems that you always have to encapsulate the element with another div that uses "if: myObservable". Suchits answer below still throws errors, though it would be nice if it worked that way.

Comment: just use `if (lastName())`. ko.observable() gives you a function, `lastName()` is the getter, and `lastName(newLastName)` is the setter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know the OP's question/example was in JavaScript, but I stumbled on this question because of the title:

> How to check if a value is NULL or unassigned in knockout.js?

This can ALSO be checked in the view, very simply:
(example is from Knockout's example code [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)):

```
<div data-bind="if: capital">
      Capital: <b data-bind="text: capital.cityName"> </b>
 </div>
```

In this example there is an object called capital and the `if` statement checks for null by default. If Capital is not null, then the second line is executed, otherwise it skips it. This works really well for simple cases.

Answer (score 7):

you can check like:

```
if(lastName  != undefined  && lastName().length > 0 ){

// do something else.
}
```

Edit: You have to invoke `lastName` as a function because it is an observable to read its current value.